# Blackberry plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

i want to convert my .apk to bar file for blackberry app world.By google i found that i have to install 2 plugin for eclipse.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java

and other

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/downloads/eclipseplugin/beta/

by installing[image: By installing plugin it should show blackberry tools]

[image: and the prefernces it should show Blackberry and Blackberry Plugin.and it show only Blackberry Plugin]

i thing the plugin has changed their url.plz help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "BlackBerry Java" plugin is for development targeting devices up to BB7. It is not related to Android at all.

To run Android Apps on Playbook or BB10, you need the plugin from this site: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/

Comment: if blackberry version 7 is for blackberry only.then which version should i install to get above thing

Answer (score 0):

1) For converting Android Apps to BB 10 platform first you must have API 10 installed(compulsory needed)

2)In Eclipse,Go to Help->Install new software->Add then use the following URL 
http://developer.blackberry.com/android/downloads/eclipseplugin/

3) Download the plugin and the rest you know it.